# Use a media player in Linux just to play files from an iPod device (no sync, no manage, just play)?

Tags: linux, ipod

I have an ipod classic 160gb, that I sync with my machine at home.

I use Linux at work, and want to just plug my ipod and just listen to the tracks, with all the playlists and such. I don't want to sync nothing, I just want to listen to the tracks as if I was using the ipod itself.

Why? Because this way I can use the usb port.

So, I don't want to **manage** my ipod in Linux, I just want to listen to the tracks on it in Linux, like it was a local library but it's instead in my ipod.

(I've tried gtkpod, it works to show my files, but I can't play, shuffle, etc. It would be interesting to have a complete audio software to handle everything like it was a local library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Rhythmbox](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/), while you can also **manage** your ipod, you can simply browse it and play from it.

Comment: It works, but I needed to plug my iPod and select "open with rythmbox" in the windows that appeared in my Ubuntu. If I just open rythmbox and try to add the ipod it just doesn't work. You can edit your answer to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Amarok will play directly from an iPod.